# How to import .txt with characters and numbers in Sas

Tags: import, sas

I want to import a .txt file in SAS.

Here what looks like my data :

```
annee manufacturier modele categorie cylindree cylindres transmission ville ...
2016  Ford           Focus    1          1.8       5      Manual       10.1
2016  Toyota         Tercel   3          1.4       3      Auto         7.1
```

Here is my code

```
data car; 
infile "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\sas\car.txt" 
LRECL=10000000 DLM=" " firstobs=2 ;
input
annee manufacturier modele categorie cylindree cylindres transmission type ville route combine emissiond indice
;
run;
```

But, when I run it, I have a lot of " Invalid data for ... " and then I end up with very few data in my table in SAS and lots of missing ones.

Some variables are numbers and some are characters. I feel like the problem is there.

How I could import that type of file ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A text file does not have any intrinsic data type.  Everything is character, until you **explicitly** tell SAS the data type of your columns.  Also, sometimes you need to tell SAS the input format, or informat, of your data.

Sometimes SAS is smart enough to guess correctly re: your data informat.  For example, the below code generates the same results if you delete the informat statement.  But, this would not be the case for say dates.  In general, explicitly specifying the informat is best practice.

If your data was delimited, such as CSV, you could use PROC IMPORT to import your data.  Using PROC IMPORT, SAS will make a best guess as to the data type based on the content of the columns (like Excel does when it imports text data).

The below code will import the data you specified:

```
filename temp temp;
data _null_;
   infile datalines;
   file temp;
   input;
   put _infile_;
   datalines;
annee manufacturier modele categorie cylindree cylindres transmission ville
2016  Ford           Focus    1          1.8       5      Manual       10.1
2016  Toyota         Tercel   3          1.4       3      Auto         7.1
run;

data want;
   infile temp firstobs=2;
   length 
      annee             8
      manufacturier     $20
      modele            $20
      categorie         8
      cylindree         8
      cylindres         8
      transmission      $20
      ville             8
   ;
   informat
      cylindree         8.1
      ville             8.1
   ;
   input
      annee            
      manufacturier    
      modele           
      categorie        
      cylindree        
      cylindres        
      transmission     
      ville            
   ;
run;
```

If your data contained spaces, for example manufacturier = Mercedes Benz, then you would need to use an informat (eg. $char20.) for that column as well.